# Can I send messages to another XboxLiveUser within the Creators Program Xbox Live API?

Tags: c#, xbox-live

I want to send a text message from the logged in Xbox Live User to another User. Can i do it with the current available API (C#) and how?

Have scanned the source files but did not find something. May I overlooked?

Edited:
I have added a new idea to Xbox User Voice to include Xbox Live Messaging into the APIS. For people looking into this question please vote for it too [Xbox User Voice](https://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/363186--new-ideas/suggestions/18803650-allow-devs-in-the-xbox-live-creators-program-to-ac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, User Messaging is not supported with the Xbox Creators Program.

You can add this as an idea to the [Xbox User Voice](https://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/363186--new-ideas/category/196261-xbox-live-creators-program) (make sure to put it in the Xbox Live Creators Program category) so that we can track interest and update you when any changes occur.

Comment: Thank you. Will add this to user voice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XBOX live REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/xbox-live-rest/uri/users/uri-usersxuidoutboxpost